# Optional argument keeps pointing to same value

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I'm trying to write a function that randomizes a list in Python 2.7.3. The code that does it is this:

```
import random

def randomize_list(l, new=[]):
    if not len(l):
        return new

    print id(l), id(new)

    l1 = list(l)

    new.append(l1.pop(
        random.choice(list(range(len(l1))))
    ))

    return randomize_list(l1, new)
```

If I import this function, and call it multiple time, the `id(new)`, always returns the same value, and each subsequent call to `randomize_function` adds items to the results of previous invocation. So, for example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> randomize_list(a)
35192344 35234016
16126176 35234016
16126536 35234016
16126896 35234016
[2,3,4,1]
>>> randomize_list(a)
35192344 35234016
35193488 35234016
35193344 35234016
16126608 35234016
[2,3,4,1,3,2,1,4]
... and so on
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not to mention, in your particular case **you are reinventing the wheel**; the same `random` module provides a `shuffle` function already that does what you want (just make a copy first).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know that. I was just exercising, and stumpled into this oddity.